# Load more data when NSCollectionView is scrolled to end of content (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, scroll, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

In my macOS application I have an `NSCollectionView`. I downloaded data and put that in the collection view, and now I want to load more data when the user scrolls to the bottom of the available content. On iOS, I could do something like this with `UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate:)`, but I'm unsure how to do this on macOS.

How can I trigger a load when the user scrolls to the bottom of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks, I solved it. Create an observation. And connect nscollectionview's scrollview and use this when I scrolling..:

```
if (self.scrollViewColl.verticalScroller?.floatValue.isEqual(to: 1.0))! && loading == false
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach that I have used on iOS is to trigger the load when a particular item is displayed. On macOS, this can be accomplished using the `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forRepresentedObjectAt)` method of `NSCollectionViewDelegate`. Something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, willDisplay item: NSCollectionViewItem, forRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == self.lastIndexPath {
        loadNextSection()
    }
}

func loadNextSection() {
    guard let self.loading == false else {
        return
    }
    self.loading = true
    self.loader.loadSection(nextSection) { objects in
        self.nextSection += 1
        self.sections.append(objects)
        self.lastIndexPath = IndexPath(indexes: [self.sections.count, objects.count])
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the correct `NSCollectionView` object name but you mention "iOS" in your answer.  Is your answer for macOS or iOS?

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned iOS because I haven't used this particular API on macOS, but it is analogous to the `UICollectionView`/`UITableView` solutions that I have experience with. Since @Blantrek brought up experience with iOS I also wanted to make a connection between something he may have used and what is available on macOS. All APIs mentioned here are usable on macOS. I've edited my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: @Jumhyn your guard let self.loading == false else {
        return
    }
not a good pattern

Comment: @Jumhyn willDisplay load more cell than i want so it the app download earlier and more than i want. I saw a mac app where i scrolled to bottom than load more data. So some kind of delegate is there to collectionview scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can check if the `indexPath.item` is equal to the `data source array count`, if so call the method that loads data in data source array.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, willDisplay item: NSCollectionViewItem, forRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == self.data_source_array.count-1 {
       self.method_to_load_more_data()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `reloadData()` collection view after adding more data.